# How to prevent logging of pyspark 'answer received' and 'command to send' messages

Tags: python, logging, pyspark

I am using python logging with pyspark and pyspark DEBUG level messages are flooding my log file with the example shown. How do I prevent this from happening? A simple solution is to set log level to INFO, but I need to log my own python DEBUG level messages

```
2015-12-13 15:13:32 4906 DEBUG   : Command to send: j
i
rj
org.apache.spark.SparkConf
e

2015-12-13 15:13:32 4906 DEBUG   : Answer received: yv
2015-12-13 15:13:32 4906 DEBUG   : Command to send: j
i
rj
org.apache.spark.api.java.*
e

2015-12-13 15:13:32 4906 DEBUG   : Answer received: yv
2015-12-13 15:13:32 4906 DEBUG   : Command to send: j
i
rj
org.apache.spark.api.python.*
e
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set logging level for each logger separately

```
 pyspark_log = logging.getLogger('pyspark')
 pyspark_log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I used following and all worked fine.

`pyspark_log = logging.getLogger('pyspark').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`
`py4j_logger = logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)`
`matplotlib_logger = logging.getLogger("matplotlib").setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

I was getting some matplotlib lib logs also, so I changed matplotlib logger level too, but if you don't have that issue you can remove that line.

Answer (score 3):

The key component is "py4j". You just need to add a line of code to the beginning of your program:

```
py4j_logger = logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Or just:

```
logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('py4j').setLevel(logging.INFO) # use setLevel(logging.ERROR) is also fine
logging.getLogger('pyspark')

logging.info('Task is successful.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control pyspark and py4j logging is by setting the following snippet:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(<pyspark-level>)
logging.getLogger('pyspark').setLevel(<py4j-level>)
logger = logging.getLogger('pyspark')
```

For your case you should write:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('pyspark').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger = logging.getLogger('pyspark')
```